# Encryption/Decryption written in c in android

Tags: android, encryption, java-native-interface

I want to know that Is there any way to write an encryption decryption code in c for a pdf file and call it from our Android app through JNI? Please suggest me if you have any clue on the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do the have the name of an encryption library in mind?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You need Android NDK -> https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html
Regards